# How to apply fixed position on slides in Swiper.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, parallax, swiper.js

Say i have a simple swiper created with idangerous Swiper.js library. Here is [codepen link](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GXXGVP) and [jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/pqoyL9wz/) How do i make it so that slides stay fixed and the content below moves on top of slides during scrolling ? I had tried messing with position:fixed and some Parallax libraries. Apparently position:fixed css property does not work with transformed elements.

HTML:

```
<div class="content">
<div class="swiper-container">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image: url(https://source.unsplash.com/random?sig=24);">
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image: url(https://source.unsplash.com/random?sig=53);"> 
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image: url(https://source.unsplash.com/random?sig=52);">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
    <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
    <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
</div>
    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitati.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitati.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitati. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitati.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitati.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitati. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitati.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitati.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitati. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitati.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitati.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitati.</p> 
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.swiper-slide {
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 50%;
    min-height: 80vh;
}
```

JS:

```
var Swipes = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
    loop: true,
    navigation: {
        nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
        prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
    },
    pagination: {
        el: '.swiper-pagination',
    },
});
```

Comment: Could you add the jsfiddle link?

Comment: Sure [jsfidde link](https://jsfiddle.net/pqoyL9wz/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `transition` works after the `element` is placed in the document layout.
So to fix the issues , you have to set the `position:fixed` to the `swiper-container`.

```
.swiper-container{
 position:fixed;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 width:100%;
}
```

[Simple Example based on your code.](https://jsfiddle.net/pqoyL9wz/15/)